# How to mirror ListView to Database?

Tags: android, sql, listview, android-listview

I have a database with a table that stores int and string. The integer value is the primary key. I have created a function to just fetch the strings from the database and store them in a list which is then applied to the ListView using an ArrayAdapter as shown below.

```
List<String> list = db.getAllStringNotes();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

The trouble is deleting from this listview. Since the primary key is not present along with the string, I was deleting using the position of the item selected from the list view. But that obviously messes up things if I'm removing an entry from the middle of the list.

So was wondering if I could add the primary key i.e. an integer value to this list view along with the String but not display the integer value?

Comment: You wil need to write a Custom List Adapter in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple thing is create two List,

```
1. String - Stored String notes
2. Integer - Stored all Primary Keys
```

So whenever user click on `Listview` user get its position, and based on that position get primary key value from second list and then perform your delete query.

Comment: I did think of this, but is that the ideal way to implement it? as in, does Android have support something for this, some CustomAdapter, something?

Comment: Please take a look of SimpleCursor Adapter.

Comment: Thanks... will look it up

Comment: Here is the link http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this: but as you are already using an ArrayList so i would suggest just make another arraylist while fetching from database:

So while deleting using the position :
Use the Primary Key from the **PrimaryKeyArrayList**
and delete values from both the ArrayList;

With this you will get exactly what you need;

Comment: Yeah... thought of this the first time, but wanted a cleaner implementation. Could you suggest what are the other ways of getting something like this done?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these  Steps:

1. Create **bean.java** file that will have  your db value
2. Create **CustomAdapter.java** to pupulate the items and handle the delete operation
3. Create **delete method** in your adapter and pass the selected bean object to delete from DB and ArrayList.
4. after deletion call **notifyDatasetChanged** method to reflect the change in list

EDIT:

**Bean File:**

```
public class MyDB_Bean{
   public int id;
   public String data;
   MyDB_Bean(int id,String data){
     this.id=id;
     this.data=data;
   }
}
```

**Calling from Activity**

```
ArrayList<MyDB_Bean> list = db.getAllStringNotes();
MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter<String>(this,list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

For **CustomAdapter** follow these tutorials

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

[Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html

Comment: Ah Thanks! Will surely look all of this up and try to create my own Adapter.